# How to return certain fields when using EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to EF Core. I am trying to get a list of all Customer who have got an item on loan and an item name. I need to return certain fields.

The following linq query works fine and returns all the records.

```
using (var context = new dbContext())
{
    var list = context.ItemStock
                      .Include(x => x.Item)
                      .Include(x => x.FullName) // Customer Name
                      .Where(l => l.LoanExpiryDate != null)
                      .ToList();

    return list;
}

public class ItemStock
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LoanExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public Customer? FullName { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

How can I return an item name and Customer name?

I have tried this so far and i get an error saying 'ItemStock doesn't contain the definition of ItemName';

```
var list = context.ItemStock
                .Where(l => l.LoanExpiryDate != null)
                .Select(x => new ItemStock
                {
                    ItemName = x.Item.Name,
                    CustomerName = x.FullName,
                })
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

EF Core is an ORM just like others, it returns entities that are just classes representing each DB row. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

If you want to flatten out the data and only return certain fields, you can do a projection

```
var list ...
return list.Select(x=> new {x.Item.Name, x.FullName.FullName}).ToList();
```

You can use a Tuple<string, string> (not ideal in some cases)
Or more commonly, map your values to a new object and return that object:

```
var list...
return list.Select(x=> new YourNewObject()
     {
          ItemName = x.Item.Name, 
          CustomerName = x.FullName.FullName
     })
.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting error "YourNewObject()" doesn't contain the definition of ItemName. In my case the new object is ItemStock.

Comment: The first bit of code uses an anonymous object to project the data into.  In the 2nd, you should create a new class called `YourNewObject`, that has those 2 properties.  You should NOT map a projection into your domain/database class because it's not a true representation of the data retrieved.